# SQL - How do I extract from the same field the hour + minute and also the year?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains transactions. Only one field refers to the time of the transaction - tran_create_date
Within it there is a date + hour + minute + second
I have to pull out (With SQL query):
For transactions made in 2017
How many were carried out every hour of the day.
To extract "Year" I used YEAR for the field tran_create_date
How do I do WHERE for "Hour + Minute"?

```
SELECT SUM (TRAN_ID) 
FROM Transactions_Table
WHERE YEAR (TRAN_CREATE_DATE) = 2017
AND HOUR (TRAN_CREATE_DATE) = 15
```

Error:
'HOUR' is not a recognized built-in function name.

thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question

Comment: If this is SQL server then search `DATEPART`

Comment: Why did you think it **was** a built-in function? Are you trying to learn T-SQL through trial and error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(TRAN_ID) FROM Transactions_Table WHERE YEAR(TRAN_CREATE_DATE) = 2017 AND DATEPART(HOUR,TRAN_CREATE_DATE) = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

... you can use it on any granularity type i.e.:

```
DATEPART(YEAR, [date])

DATEPART(MONTH, [date]) 

DATEPART(DAY, [date])    

DATEPART(HOUR, [date]) 

DATEPART(MINUTE, [date])
```

(note: I like the [ ] around the date reserved word though. Of course that's in case your column with timestamp is labeled "date")